# Выдаёт ошибку при запуске gulp через node.js

Tags: javascript, вёрстка, gulp

Помогите решить, пожалуйста мою проблему.

Вот ошибка

```
assert.js:385
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Verstka\Level2.0\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Verstka\Level2.0\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Verstka\Level2.0\gulpfile.js:119:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1133:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1153:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:977:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:877:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1019:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
    at execute (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gulp\node_modules\gulp-cli\lib\versioned\^4.0.0\index.js:36:18) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```

Вот мой package.json

```
{
  "name": "level2.0",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.2.3",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-clean-css": "latest",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-sass": "latest",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.1.1",
    "imagemin-pngquant": "^4.0.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.13.1",
    "rimraf": "^2.3.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

Вот мой bower.json

```
{
  "name": "level2.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "ISC",
  "homepage": "",
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "test",
    "tests"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0"
  },
  "overrides": {
    "bootstrap": {
        "main": [
            "./dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
            "./dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ]
    }
  }
}
```

Вот мой gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

    var gulp = require('gulp'),
    mainBowerFiles = require('main-bower-files'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    prefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
    uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css'),
    imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    pngquant = require('imagemin-pngquant'),
    rimraf = require('rimraf'),
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
    vendor: {
        js: 'app/js/',
        css: 'app/css/'
    },
    dist: { //Тут мы укажем куда складывать готовые после сборки файлы
        html: 'dist/',
        js: 'dist/js/',
        scss: 'dist/css/',
        css: 'dist/css/',
        img: 'dist/img/',
        fonts: 'dist/fonts/'
    },
    app: { //Пути откуда брать исходники
        html: 'app/*.html', //Синтаксис src/*.html говорит gulp что мы хотим взять все файлы с расширением .html
        js: 'app/js/*.js',//В стилях и скриптах нам понадобятся только main файлы
        scss: 'app/css/*.scss',
        css: 'app/css/*.css',
        img: 'app/img/**/*.*', //Синтаксис img/**/*.* означает - взять все файлы всех расширений из папки и из вложенных каталогов
        fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    watch: { //Тут мы укажем, за изменением каких файлов мы хотим наблюдать
        html: 'app/**/*.html',
        js: 'app/js/**/*.js',
        scss: 'app/css/**/*.scss',
        css: 'app/css/**/*.css',
        img: 'app/img/**/*.*',
        fonts: 'app/fonts/**/*.*'
    },
    clean: './dist'
};

var config = {
    server: {
        baseDir: "./dist"
    },
    tunnel: true,
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 8081,
    logPrefix: "WAYUP"
};

gulp.task('vendorJs:build', function () {
    gulp.src( mainBowerFiles('**/*.js') ) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.vendor.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в app
});

gulp.task('vendorCss:build', function () {
    gulp.src( mainBowerFiles('**/*.css') ) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.vendor.css)) //И в app
});

gulp.task('html:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.html) //Выберем файлы по нужному пути
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.html)) //Выплюнем их в папку build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим наш сервер для обновлений
});

gulp.task('js:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.js) //Найдем наш main файл
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //Инициализируем sourcemap
        .pipe(uglify()) //Сожмем наш js
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write()) //Пропишем карты
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.js)) //Выплюнем готовый файл в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true})); //И перезагрузим сервер
});

gulp.task('scss:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.scss) //Выберем наш main.scss
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //То же самое что и с js
        .pipe(sass()) //Скомпилируем
        .pipe(prefixer()) //Добавим вендорные префиксы
        .pipe(cleanCSS()) //Сожмем
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.scss)) //И в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('css:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.css) //Выберем наш main.css
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init()) //То же самое что и с js
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.css)) //И в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('image:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.app.img) //Выберем наши картинки
        .pipe(imagemin({ //Сожмем их
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}],
            use: [pngquant()],
            interlaced: true
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.img)) //И бросим в build
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('fonts:build', function() {
    gulp.src(path.app.fonts)
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.dist.fonts))
});

gulp.task('build', [
    'vendorCss:build',
    'vendorJs:build',
    'html:build',
    'js:build',
    'scss:build',
    'css:build',
    'fonts:build',
    'image:build'
]);

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.html], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('html:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.scss], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('scss:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.css], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('css:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.js], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('js:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.img], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('image:build');
    });
    watch([path.watch.fonts], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('fonts:build');
    });
});

gulp.task('webserver', function () {
    browserSync(config);
});

gulp.task('clean', function (cb) {
    rimraf(path.clean, cb);
});

gulp.task('default', ['build', 'webserver', 'watch']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитайте про обновление gulp v4. Весь файл gulp.js нужно обновлять, используя parallel и serialise.
Либо откатывайтесь до gulp v3, что не разумно)